# Why data in minio transfers more quickly when use explorer to download？

Tags: python, amazon-s3, networking, download, minio

I'm developing projects for a university，and its minio server is deployed in education network，so when I use `python.minio` or `mc.exe` to download data to public network，its speed can’t bigger than 3MB/s.
However when I download data from minio console in explorer，strange things happened：

[image]

It's obvious that request in explorer had transferred only 245.33MB，however the file `gpm_gfs.nc` which I want to download is about **2.3GB**；total time cost is about 2.16min.

And about a month ago，downloading data from explorer's minio console will be catched by explorer's download manager，and its average speed is ~50MB/s. The explorer doesn't use other proxies.

So can anyone tell me why data transfers faster in explorer？And how can I optimize my code or network to break speed limitation of education network?